# How to get specific array value in session?

Tags: php

```
Array ( [S10_2016] => Array ( [productName] => 1996 Moto Guzzi 1100i [productCode] => S10_2016 [MSRP] => 118.94 [quantity] => 1 ) )
```

```
print_r($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);
```

Above is my print r result. I have problem with displaying specific array value in this session. I want to get the value "productCode, MSRP and quantity" to store in a database after user click on checkout button.

Answer (score 1):

Since you probably have no way of knowing that the keys are in `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']` you need to iterate it using a foreach:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $product) {
    $productCode = $product['productCode'];
    $MSRP = $product['MSRP'];
    $quantity = $product['quantity'];
    // insert to database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below code. Here I placed key then placed productname, code etc...

[## LIVE Example ##](https://eval.in/1100493)

```
$_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array(
        "S10_2016" =>array(
                "productName"=> '1996 Moto Guzzi 1100i',
                "productCode"=> 'S10_2016',
                "MSRP"=> 118.94,
                "quantity"=> 1
            ),
        );
$body='';
  foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $val) {

    $body .= $key . "--productName: " . $val['productName'] ."\r\n";
    $body .= $key . "--productCode: " . $val['productCode'] ."\r\n";
    $body .= $key . "--MSRP: " . $val['MSRP'] ."\r\n";
    $body .= $key . "--quantity: " . $val['quantity'] ."\r\n";
}

echo $body;

?>
```